# Debug global variable in eclipse - Java/Android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, debugging

I'm debugging with eclipse an Android app but I can not see the value of `Global Static Variables`.

```
public class Example{
    private static int variable;

    public void someFunct(){
       //some code
       int aux = variable;
       // some code
    } 
}
```

I can check the value if assign to a local variable the global variable value, but I can't see the global variable while debugging.

How can I solve it?

Comment: What do you mean with global variables? static variables?

Comment: post the relevant code pls

Comment: yes, global static variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put watch on that `Variable` when you debug. and you can see in "`Expression`" tab inside of `Debug` Perspective

Right click on global Variable then select `watch`